# Magento Admin “Send Email” button not working

Tags: magento, email, magento-1.8

I am having an issue with the "Send Email" button on order view pages within the Magento admin panel. I am having this issue on two separate installations of Magento ver. 1.8.1.0 on four servers, so I am assuming it as a bug at this point. I just installed a completely fresh version and tested it again with the same issue.

I have gone as far as installing a fresh copy of 1.7 side by side with 1.8.1.  1.7 sends that particular email just fine, 1.8.1 does not.

Has anyone else experienced this or have any suggestions for a debug process?

Comment: @woomanhodal Check your magento and the apache logs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just been looking into this myself. I've followed the code and functions back to this function "public function sendNewOrderEmail()" in:

app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php

starting at line 1270 is the following code:

```
$emailSentAttributeValue = $this->load($this->getId())->getData('email_sent');
    $this->setEmailSent((bool)$emailSentAttributeValue);
    if ($this->getEmailSent()) {
        return $this;
    }
```

This is checking the sales_flat_order db table to see if the email has already been sent to the customer and if so just to return, but this does not send the email and should throw an error. So I would say it is a bug somewhere.
To fix it so you can resend order/invoice emails etc..

Copy

app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php

to

app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php

and comment out line 1273

```
if ($this->getEmailSent()) {
            //return $this;
        }
```

Works a charm for me. But literally only this second tested it.

Tested using ver. 1.8.1

Comment: THANKS! I just tested that on 1.9.0.1 and it appears to work great!  Are there any potential side effects from this fix that you know of?

Comment: That code only checks to see it the emails has already been sent so the only side effect would be if you sent the email again the customer may think they have double ordered or been invoiced twice. But you would only resend the order or invoice email if the customer has requested it or has not received the original order/invoice.

Comment: Just chiming in saying I just tested this in 1.9.0.1 and it also worked for me.

Comment: I've put this "fix" in place on 1.9.0.1 but I still can't get it to work. Has anyone got any ideas?!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with fresh installs of 1.8, 1.8.1 and even 1.9.  My solution for now since it doesn't seem to be acknowledged as a bug yet was to just back up to 1.7.2.  Hopefully this bug gets fixed so we can upgrade.

Comment: Same process I went through.  Try ScarletRed's fix, it appears to work on 1.8.1 and 1.9.0.1.